# Is STI appropriate if model can be multiple subclasses at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When is the correct time to use STI in a Rails app? After a lot of reading (including [this excellent Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/394-sti-and-polymorphic-associations)) I'm still unsure what is the best approach for my needs.

This (contrived) example illustrates my dilemma.

Lets say a User class could categorized in several sub-classes, including Doctors and Patients. These are more than simple roles, with key data and logic differences.

A Doctor has certain database fields (e.g., qualification, speciality), certain view logic (e.g. `if User.doctor? then` display list of patients), and certain logic and roles (e.g. can manage patient records).

A Patient has different database fields (e.g., blood type), view logic (e.g. `if User.patient?  then` display list of treatments), and logic (e.g. can edit appointments).

Both Doctors and Patients have `:username, :email,  :password` fields in common, as well as a considerable amount of logic throughout the remainder of the app (e.g., `User has_many :comments, :messages, etc` ).

From my reading, the fact that Patients and Doctors have different logic requirements suggests STI may be appropriate. But with different database fields, polymorphic may be a better approach.

BUT....

A User may be both a Doctor and a Patient simultaneously.

Is there a "best approach" to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

STI uses a single column to determine the object's type.

At first glance this would indicate you'd need to have User, Doctor, Patient, and DoctorPatient classes, which to me, seems a little loopy. It could potentially get even loopier if other types are added.

Moving Doctor, Patient, etc. functionality into another class (and table) seems like it'd make more sense, without knowing anything more, but other folks may have more useful input.

Comment: thanks for this suggestion. This would certainly solve the "differences" part of this problem, but there also a lot of similarities between Doctors and Patients: shared login and authentication, shared child models, etc. I worry this would result in a lot of repetition elsewhere in the app. Appreciate your thoughts

Comment: @AndyHarvey There's nothing that says a `User` can't have an associated `Doctor` model (etc.) or that decisions (authorizations, for example) can't rely on the presence (or lack) of doctor/patient associations.

Comment: yes, you're right. I think perhaps I am overcomplicating this by thinking about STI, polymorphics, etc, when actually all that is needed is a User with various child models. Out of interest, as this will be one-to-one relationship, how would you set up the relationships in Rails?